# Changing database field when user logs into account

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to update a database table to change a field when a user logs in.  When the user inputs his/her correct information, a query runs to change the field from 0 to 1.  However, this does not happen.  I'm assuming that my query statement is wrong.  Can anyone explain to me what I did wrong with the statement and what I should do to fix it?

```
<?php
    session_start();
    require("../includes/header.php");
    if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
        $p_num = $_POST["username"];
        $pwd = $_POST["password"];

        $query = "SELECT * FROM $user_table";
        $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
            $user_id = "{$row['user_id']}";
            $user_name = "{$row['user_name']}";
            $password = "{$row['password']}";
            $image = "{$row['image']}";
            $email = "{$row['email']}";
            $program = "{$row['program']}";
            $role = "{$row['role']}";
            $logged_in = "{$row['logged_in']}";

            if(($user_id == $p_num) && ($pwd == $password)){
                $_SESSION["id"] = $user_id;
                $_SESSION["user"] = $user_name;
                $_SESSION["program"] = $program;
                $_SESSION["pass"] = $password;
                $_SESSION["image"] = $image;
                $_SESSION["email"] = $email;
                $_SESSION["role"] = $role;
                $_SESSION["logged in"] = $logged_in;

                mysqli_query($connect, "UPDATE '{$user_table}' SET logged_in = 1 WHERE user_id = '{$p_num}'");

                header("Location: ../pages/instructor.php");
            }
            else{
                header("Refresh: 1; URL=../index.php");
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: are you sure about `$p_num = $_POST["username"];` and `if(($user_id == $p_num)` ?

Comment: why you loop all users, instead try using where close and get the user you want, and before that please debug the value of $user_id after this statement $user_id = "{$row['user_id']}";

Comment: zarkone, yes I am because the login script works perfectly.

AbdullaChozhimadathil, doing a where clause in the SQL statement will do the exact same thing as the if statement.  Plus, I need to get other values from the database when the user logs in to pass into another page, that's why I'm looping through everything

Comment: I'm also not understanding what you mean by `debug the value of $user_id after this statement $user_id = "{$row['user_id']}";`

Answer (score 0):

I actually figured this out myself.  I was simply checking for the wrong values in the sql statement.